# Where to bind observable getters in Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In Polymer.dart I'm aware that there are no strictly observable getters, and that instead we need to use `bindProperty()` (Soon to be `onPropertyChange()`) and `notifyProperty()` to simulate the same thing.

Looking through various code samples, I see some locations where this is added in to the constructor of the PolymerElement's class, and others where the binding happens in the `created()` method. Is there a preference as to where binding should occur? Are there any significant benefits or detriments on putting them in one of these areas or another?

Answer (score 1):

Putting `bindProperty` into the constructor no longer works in polymer.dart >= 0.8. I am in the process of changing all my samples.

I am now using `created` as the location where I put my `onPropertyChange` or similar calls.

Comment: Was this due to the name change and not due to the location (bindProperty is now onPropertyChange)? I still have it in the constructor with the onPropertyChange method and it works fine in >=0.8

Comment: Constructors should come back once we wire in true element extends. So, just hang type. :)